# PyQGIS identify if running from console?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm writing some diagnostic PyQGIS code. How can the code determine if it has been invoked from the QGIS python console?

Basically, I have

```
def diagnosticRoutine()
   message = "blah blah {}".format(stuff())
```

Then, if `diagnosticRoutine()` was invoked from the Python Console, I want to `print(message)` to just have it appear there. But if it is being invoked otherwise, e.g. from processing, startup.py or a project macro), I want to `QgsMessageLog.logMessage(message)` instead, since `print()` would be hazardous.

How can I tell which it is?

(QGIS 3.28+)

Comment: have you tried checking the `__name__`  to determine this? 
for example `print(__name__)`  should show you different results in console, startup.py and so on

Comment: That has real potential - I get `__name__="__console__"` when running the Python Console. Will explore further....thanks.